# AWS System manager run command failed with TERMINATED status

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-ssm

I'm trying to use SSM run command to run "echo 'hello world'" (to test communication with the windows app servers and then run a more elaborated powershell script) but I noticed that the command failed to some instances and succeeded for another ones. The problem is that the command actually didn't completely failed, but the detailed status shows "terminated". Any ideas what could be a possible cause for that?

```
---
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Command Document Example JSON Template"
parameters:
  Message:
    type: "String"
    description: "Example"
    default: "Hello World"
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runPowerShellScript"
  name: "example"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
    - "echo {{Message}}"
```

[image]

Comment: What does the SSM command log say?

Comment: It says nothing, the output and error returned 0.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I tried to run the command on more instances than the configured concurrency control. Once I increased the rate control the command ran successfully in all the instances.

[image]